# How to write my own job in samza

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-samza, stream-processing

Recently I am trying to do some stream processing work on Samza framework. I have deployed the hello-samza example successfully. However, when I try to write my own job, I have no idea where to start my work.

I have read [this document](http://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.9/), but I still can't get the point. So can anyone help me:

1. What is my code's architecture (source code, lib code, and configuration).
2. Which directory will my code pushed in.
3. What other work I need to do to get my codes run.

Your suggestion will help me a lot, many thanks!

Comment: That is the point of the hello-samza project - to show 1) what the architecture looks like (source code, lib code and configuration), 2) which directory is your code pushed in (which you'd know assuming you did deploy it successfully) and 3) all the code needed to get it to run.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to build your own Jobs. First get hello samza:

```
git clone https://git.apache.org/samza-hello-samza.git hello-samza
```

The next step is to set up the system by these command:

```
bin/grid bootstrap
```

Please make sure that all is going good by `jps`

The next step is to remove apache-rat-plugin from pom.xml instead of building your project inside hello-samza.

When you remome that you can add a java file Job in src folder(MyTask.java) and also a .properties file inside config directory (My.Task.properties)

This is a sample-empty Job(MyTask.java).

```
package com.samza;
public class MyTask implements StreamTask {
    private static final SystemStream OUTPUT_STREAM = new SystemStream("kafka","topicOut"); 
    public void process (IncomingMessageEnvelope envelope,                  MessageCollector collector,                 
    TaskCoordinator coordinator) throws Exception { 
        // Do something useful
    }
}
```

Don't forget to implement a .properties file.

If you hava non-error code, build with maven like:

```
mvn clean package
mkdir -p deploy/samza
tar -xvf ./samza-job-package/target/samza-job-package-0.10.0-dist.tar.gz -C deploy/samza
```

After that and your server is up (if it is not you can started by `./bin/grid start all)` you can deploy your Job by `deploy/samza/bin/run-job.sh --config-factory=org.apache.samza.config.factories.PropertiesConfigFactory --config-path=file://$PWD/deploy/samza/config/MyTask.properties`

and consume the result by kafka client-consumer 
`deploy/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic outTopic`

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the Hello Samza instructions, you will have a fully functioning Zookeeper, Kafka, and Yarn/Samza cluster running on your local computer. With that project there are the Wikipedia feed related tasks that you can run to test things.

However, like you, I had some trouble coming up with the proper directory structure and build settings for new tasks (without the cluster management stuff). So, I created [hello-samza-base](https://github.com/benmanns/hello-samza-base) by stripping out everything unnecessary for new tasks outside of hello-samza. I included instructions in the README on building new tasks.

As far as deployment goes, that is a bit more complex. Do some reading on creating Zookeeper, Kafka, and Yarn clusters.

Answer (score 0):

I created Samza jobs parting via a Maven Eclipse project. The dependencies for version 0.9.2 where loaded in the pom.xml file with this content (I had some version issues, so you may have some work there):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.acio.samza</groupId>
      <artifactId>samzafroga</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <name>samzafroga</name>
       <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-core_2.10</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-shell</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-yarn_2.10</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
                <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-kv_2.10</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-kv-rocksdb_2.10</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
          <artifactId>samza-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.schwering</groupId>
          <artifactId>irclib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
       </dependencies>
      <properties>
        <!-- maven specific properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <samza.version>0.8.0</samza.version>
        <jettyVersion>7.6.16.v20140903</jettyVersion>
      </properties>
        <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>apache-releases</id>
          <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>scala-tools.org</id>
          <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>scala-tools.org</id>
          <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
          <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
       <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
              <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.9</version>
              <configuration>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>*.patch</exclude>
                  <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>*.json</exclude>
                  <exclude>.vagrant/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>.git/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>*.md</exclude>
                  <exclude>docs/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>config/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>bin/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>.gitignore</exclude>
                  <exclude>**/.cache/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>deploy/**</exclude>
                  <exclude>**/.project</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </configuration>
             </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

          <!-- plugin to build the tar.gz file filled with examples -->
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
               <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
       <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-api</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-core_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-shell</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-yarn_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-kv_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-kv-rocksdb_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
                <artifactId>samza-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${samza.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.schwering</groupId>
                <artifactId>irclib</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
       </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

The basic code of a job is this one:

```
package xxxx;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.samza.config.Config;
import org.apache.samza.system.IncomingMessageEnvelope;
import org.apache.samza.system.OutgoingMessageEnvelope;
import org.apache.samza.system.SystemStream;
import org.apache.samza.task.MessageCollector;
import org.apache.samza.task.StreamTask;
import org.apache.samza.task.TaskContext;
import org.apache.samza.task.TaskCoordinator;

public class Redirect implements StreamTask {
      private final SystemStream OUTPUT_STREAM = new SystemStream("kafka", "samzaout");

     public void process(IncomingMessageEnvelope envelope,
         MessageCollector collector,
         TaskCoordinator coordinator)
     {
         String msg = (String)envelope.getMessage();
         // Transformation

         String outmsg = "xxx-" + msg + "-xxx";
         collector.send(new OutgoingMessageEnvelope(OUTPUT_STREAM, outmsg));
     }
}
```

Once you have it compiled you need to group it into a jar file and place it in a location accesible for all the samza nodes, web or hdfs.

Reference this from the properties file you will have to create to launch it. Look for examples in the porject web page.

Answer (score -2):

Read that document some more, look at the hello-samza example some more, and if you deployed it to YARN read about it some more. All the answers you're looking for are there.

There are three jobs in hello-samza. Pick one and follow it, configuration, launching scripts etc.

Here's from the hello-samza page how to launch the wikipedia-feed job

```
deploy/samza/bin/run-job.sh --config-factory=org.apache.samza.config.factories.PropertiesConfigFactory --config-path=file://$PWD/deploy/samza/config/wikipedia-feed.properties
```

The properties file shows where the compiled job/task code is among other things. The source code for the wikipedia-feed job/task is here:

https://github.com/apache/samza-hello-samza/blob/master/src/main/java/samza/examples/wikipedia/task/WikipediaFeedStreamTask.java

Just modify this job, or copy and modify, to get yours going.